# Remove object from Set after changing its field

Tags: java, set, hashcode

I have found this question during my preparation for SCJP:

```
class Key {
    public int i;

    public Key(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return i == ((Key) o).i;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return i;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Key> set = new HashSet<Key>();
        Key k1 = new Key(1);
        Key k2 = new Key(2);
        set.add(k1);
        set.add(k1);
        set.add(k2);
        set.add(k2);
        System.out.print(set.size() + “:”);
        k2.i = 1;
        System.out.print(set.size() + “:”);
        set.remove(k1);
        System.out.print(set.size() + “:”);
        set.remove(k2);
        System.out.print(set.size());
    }
}
```

the result is: `2:2:1:1`.

The question is: why after changing the field of `k2` can't it be removed?

Answer (score 3):

An object in a `HashSet` is located according to its `hashCode()`. If you change a field that causes the `hashCode()` to change, Java would be unable to locate it in the set, and thus unable to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

If you imagine how a `HashSet` works, then it becomes obvious.

Lets say you have a `HashSet` that only allows `0` or `1` hashcode values, it has two buckets:

- `1`
- `0`

When you `add` an item to the `HashSet`, the `HashSet` works out whether the `hashCode` is `1` or `0` and finds the correct bucket.

So you create your object `thing` and `setHashCode(1)`, and `add` it. The `HashSet` gets the `hashCode` and duly dumps it into the `1` bucket.

How you call `thing.setHashCode(0)` and then `remove`. What happens? Well, the `HashSet` gets the `hashCode` of `thing`, it's `0`. It looks in the `0` bucket, but when you called `add` `thing` was put into bucket `1` - the `HashSet` looks in the **wrong bucket**. The `HashSet` cannot find `thing` to remove it.

Interestingly, if you `add` `thing2` with a `hashCode` of `0`. And if you `equals` is implemented (as in your example) as `hashCode == other.hashCode`, then calling `remove(thing)` after setting `hashCode` of `thing` to `0` will actually remove **`thing2`**.

This is a good example of why the properties of an `Object` use in it's `equals` and `hashCode` properties should not be changed if the `Object` is used as a `Map` key or placed into a `Set`.